# How to operate (filter and sort) with an array of items in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the next items in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0325eec104041f38a6f9ec"),
    "total_distict_words" : 137,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "first" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "another" : 3
        }, 
{
            "house" : 5
        },

    .....
```

I am trying to sort and filter the tops words that appear into items array.

The problem is that "item" has the next template: `{ <word>: <value> }`

I was trying to operate or transform, but without success.

Firstly, *How Could I operate over "stats.items" array with mongodb and aggregation?*

Secondly, *How could I transform in a dictionary form,* eg:

```
{ "llegaron": 1 } => { word: "llegaron", counter: "1" }
```

The problem was that when I operate with some element, I have to know the name of the field that I want to access, for example:

```
# users: [<name, age, posts>]
db.users.aggregate([{ $sort : { age : -1, posts: 1 }}] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a shorter way for you to get to this but here is something to play with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  { $project: { items: { $objectToArray: "$items" } } },
  { $project: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            word: "$$item.k",
            counter: "$$item.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "items": { "$push": "$items" } } },
  { "$project": {
      "items": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  { $sort: { "items.counter": -1 }},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "items": { "$push": "$items" } } }
])
```

The idea is to use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and then [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform your `k:v` to `word: k, value: v` and then the rest is just a way to get your array items sorted via few projects/group & `$sort`.

Also we use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) & [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) to group that pesky array of arrays that ends up happening by the `{ "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "items": { "$push": "$items" } } },`.

On the end of the day use the link bellow and follow each step of the pipeline to really understand its meaning and purpose. I am sure there is a shorter way to get this same result etc ...

Also you can change the sort order in this line `{ $sort: { "items.counter": -1 }},` to 1 for `asc` and `-1` for `desc`

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X_KfYuk7pG9)